# Django's urlresolvers.reverse isn't enough, how to get the rest?

Tags: python, django

I'm sending a callback URL to a remote widely API over which I have no control.

I've written my callback view and it's properly named (say, `myapp_callback`) in my `urls.py`, so all that I have to do is to call `reverse('myapp_callback')`, right? [That's what it says in the manual.](http://That's%20what%20it%20says%20in%20the%20manual.)

Well, not so much. The result is `/myapp/callback`. Where's my protocol and hostname? The remote service I'm sending these API calls to has no idea. How can I detect it while maybe behind an Apache reverse proxy?

I'm working around this problem by putting the full URL into the settings file, but I'd love to provide a more "turnkey" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the [`request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('myapp_callback'))`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri).

> Returns the absolute URI form of location. If no location is provided, the location will be set to **request.get_full_path()**.
>
> If the location is already an absolute URI, it will not be altered. Otherwise the absolute URI is built using the server variables available in this request.
>
> Example: **"http://example.com/music/bands/the_beatles/?print=true"**